# Android VideoView fails on prepare; OMX-VDEC reports second instance

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview, prepare

The code in question:

```
public class VideoPlayer extends Activity {
    Bundle bundle;
    VideoView vv;
    String type;
    Uri path;
    Context mContext;
    ImageView countImage;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Remove title bar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //Remove notification bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.videoplayer);
        mContext = getBaseContext();
        vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        countImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.countdownNumber);
        countImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT); 

        // get details from the Bundle's extras.
        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String playMode = bundle.getString("mode");

        if (playMode.compareTo("single") == 0) { playSingle(); }
        else if (playMode.compareTo("multi") == 0) { playMulti(); }
        else { finish(); }
    }


    // --- PLAY SINGLE ---
    public void playSingle() {
        // retrieve name of video to play from the Bundle
        String videoname = bundle.getString("videoname");
        Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.sexinfo101.positions.guide/raw/video_" + videoname);
        boolean result = false;
        int test = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("video_" + videoname, "raw", mContext.getPackageName());
        if (test != 0)  { result = true; }        
        if (!result) { finish(); }

        vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        vv.setVideoURI(path);
        vv.requestFocus();
        //vv.start();

        vv.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
                vv.start();
            }
        });

        vv.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if (!mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.release();
                    finish(); // we're done here
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The logcat output:

```
08-06 15:22:30.770: ERROR/MediaPlayerService(116): Returning PV_PLAYER*************************
08-06 15:22:30.790: ERROR/PlayerDriver(116): Creating Non-Tunnel mode playback - uncompressed MIO
08-06 15:22:30.800: ERROR/OMX-VDEC-720P(116):  In OMX vdec Constuctor
08-06 15:22:30.800: ERROR/OMX-VDEC-720P(116):  Name of the device is Unknown
08-06 15:22:30.800: ERROR/OMX-VDEC-720P(116):  omx_vdec::component_init(): Start of New Playback
08-06 15:22:30.800: ERROR/OMX-VDEC-720P(116):  omx_vdec::component_init(): Open returned fd 30
08-06 15:22:31.300: ERROR/OMX-VDEC-720P(116):  Reject Second instance of Decoder
08-06 15:22:31.300: ERROR/OMX-VDEC-720P(116):  In OMX vdec Destructor
08-06 15:22:31.300: ERROR/OMX-VDEC-720P(116):  Waiting on OMX Msg Thread exit
08-06 15:22:31.300: ERROR/OMX-VDEC-720P(116):  Waiting on OMX Async Thread exit
08-06 15:22:31.300: ERROR/OMX-VDEC-720P(116):  Exit OMX vdec Destructor
08-06 15:22:31.310: ERROR/PlayerDriver(116): Command PLAYER_PREPARE completed with an error or info PVMFErrResource
08-06 15:22:31.320: ERROR/MediaPlayer(1364): error (1, -17)
08-06 15:22:31.330: ERROR/MediaPlayer(1364): Error (1,-17)
```

Followed by more logcat output:

```
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364): java.lang.IllegalStateException
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.media.MediaPlayer._reset(Native Method)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.reset(MediaPlayer.java:1061)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.widget.VideoView.release(VideoView.java:510)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.widget.VideoView.access$2100(VideoView.java:50)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.widget.VideoView$6.surfaceDestroyed(VideoView.java:500)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.view.SurfaceView.reportSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceView.java:568)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:472)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:206)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:6029)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.view.ViewRoot.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRoot.java:1630)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.view.ViewRoot.doDie(ViewRoot.java:2720)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.view.ViewRoot.die(ViewRoot.java:2690)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:218)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeViewImmediate(Window.java:436)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3684)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-06 15:24:29.400: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1364):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My suspicion is that the logcat line "08-06 17:31:29.960: ERROR/OMX-VDEC-720P(116):  Reject Second instance of Decoder" points to the cause of the failure in prepare, but I have no clue where this second instance could be coming from. It does precede the actual shutdown of the decoder, so if not the cause, it seems to at least hint at one.

Any thoughts? In the debugger I can see that a valid resource has been found, and this code used to work just fine before I swapped out Timers for Handler and Runnables in the multi-player function which I cut from the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, this turned out to be a firmware/OS/device issue. The problem may have been induced by the SuperBoot boot ROM I started using recently to gain root access on my Huawei IDEOS X5 U8800 phone. This boot ROM according to the developer was developed for firmware revision 136, and I was using 135. After upgrading everything seems to work smoothly again, including WiFi access and everything :)

The link to the forum thread discussing this issue can be found here: http://android.modaco.com/topic/340374-25-may-r1-superboot-and-then-some-for-the-huawei-u8800-ideos-x5/